# How do I test a private method with Jasmine Unit tests

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I want to call a private method in my component

**Private Method:**

```
  private test(): void {
     return true;
  }
```

**Spec It:**

```
  it('should call test method and return true', () => {
     const response = component.test();
     expect(response).toBeTruthy();
  });
```

**Issue:**

> Says: "Property 'test' is private and only accessible within class
>   'MyTestComponent'."

Comment: make a public wrapper for test purposes?

Comment: Seems like its by design

Comment: Why do you want to test a private method? Testing implementation details is not a good idea, isn't it? I think that you should test only public methods because it's api of your component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use

```js
component['test']();
// OR in your component, add
callMethod() {
  this.test();
}
```

But if I were you, I would remove the private attribute. In Javascript, there's no private attributes, only scopes.

If you want to test your method and you can't, it means you should change your code, not adapt your test to your code. That's how you get simple and efficient code.

(But again; that was just my two cents on your matter)

Comment: Im using typescript

Comment: Just because Typescript is compiled to Javascript we should not use private functions? Then we can abandon the whole Typescript concept anyway.