# Jasmine test case for a private function inside a class?

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine

.ts:

```
export class TestClass {
    private method(info: Info): Info {
        return {
          number: null,
          data: {
            testDemo: info.data.flag
          },
          cc: null
        };
      }
    }
```

I'm trying to add a test case for this private method, any best approach ??

Comment: Use bracket notation.

Comment: any example references ?? @TheHeadRush

Comment: @Ramana, check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48093489/9386929

Comment: @Ramana `const result = myTestClass['method'](mockData);`

Answer (score -1):

you can not directly test a private method. But you can test it through public method if you are calling this in any public method.

Comment: What is the best option for the above function ??

Comment: You can definitely test private methods using bracket notation.

Comment: It depends on how you are using this function. The code you provided is having only one private function. For example, If you are calling this function to set some variable in another public function, you can call that public function in test case and check if the variable is set to the expected properties. But you can not directly access private members  in your jasmine test case.

Comment: @TheHeadRush Can you provide an example? I am not aware of what you are suggesting

Comment: @kesavi I put an example in the question's comment section.